# Android NotificationListernerService - how to dismiss a single notification from whatsapp stacked notification

Tags: android

I've written a NotificationListerService to get all notifications and showing them in my app.
I also use cancelNotification() to dismiss notifications.
My problem is with Whatsapp stacked notification , i cannot get a single notification to get dismissed , they keep "coming" back in onNotificationPosted.
Let's say for example that i have 2 unread notifications from 2 different numbers, if i dismiss one of them and after that i get another message from the other number (the one i did not dismiss), than in onNotificationPosted i get 2 messages again - the new one and the dismissed one.

```
@Override
public void onListenerConnected() {

    Log.d(TAG, "Got onListenerConnected");
    super.onListenerConnected();
    onNotificationChanged();
}

private void onNotificationChanged() {
    Log.d(TAG, "onNotificationChanged");
    // Update the active notifications list
    activeNotifications = getActiveNotifications();
    // Notify to listeners
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).sendBroadcast(new Intent("notification_changed"));
}

@Override
public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onNotificationPosted");
    onNotificationChanged();

}

@Override

public void onNotificationRemoved(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onNotificationRemoved");
}

public final void deleteNotificationFromNotificationBar(Model m)
{
    StatusBarNotification[] sbns = getActiveNotifications();
    for (StatusBarNotification sbn : sbns)
    {

        if (sbn.getKey().equals(m.getKeyName()))
        {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
            {
                super.cancelNotification(sbn.getKey());
            }
            else
            { 
                super.cancelNotification(sbn.getPackageName(), sbn.getTag(), sbn.getId());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did you found any solution?